# Issues Working With Encrypted Zip FIles w/ Python

Tags: python, lambda

I'm using a statement like:

```
zipf.read(file, pwd = 'password')
```

Results in an error:

```
TypeError: pwd: expected bytes, got str
```

Did some research, determined I should try this:

```
zipf.read(file, pwd = b'password')
```

Now results in error:

```
RuntimeError: Bad password for file <ZipInfo filename='smb-d1674sc2.bin' compress_type=99 external_attr=0x20 file_size=737280 compress_size=641541>
```

Feel like I am just going in circles at this point. I have also tried:

```
                password = 'password'
                passwd = password.encode("UTF-8")
                pwd = 'password'.encode('cp850','replace')
                testpass = str(b'password', 'utf-8')
```

And none of these work either (replacing my string above with these various variables)

Yes, I have tried opening the file on my system manually and can confirm the password is correct.

Additional Background: Working in Lambda, taking in an encrypted zip which is uploaded to S3. My program works with no issues for zips that are not password protected.

Comment: Not sure if this is an issue in your actual code, but take care: `pass` is not a valid variable name. If you tried using it, your code would have failed even if the encoding was correct. Not that I think `password.encode("UTF-8")` is the correct approach, since that just returns `b'password'`, but it's something to watch out for.

Comment: @Kevin Thanks, and yeah I replaced the variables I am actually using with random variations of the word password. 'pass' is not actually a variable I am trying... When using password.encode("UTF-8") I'm still getting "Bad pass for file blahblah"

Comment: Could it be because of how (with which tool) the zip archive was created? I've just tried. `zip test.zip file -e` using `password` as password. Then in Python: `z = zipfile.ZipFile('test.zip'); z.read('file', pwd=b'password')` and I got content of file `file`.

Comment: I faced with the same problem. My first archive was from ubuntu UI (using zip) and it failed for python. Then my issue disappeared when I rebuilt my zip archive with: `zip --password (password) file.zip files`